# Replace string in URL using apache

Tags: regex, apache, apache2

I am new to apache web server.

I have a URL like :-

```
www.example.com/example1/{ dynamic string }/p123465/content
```

I want to convert it into:

```
www.example.com/example1/{ dynamic string }/pid/content
```

here dynamic string is different every time.

Comment: What is difference both look same

Comment: There's no difference in either of the urls

Comment: sorry i have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(example1/[^/]+)/p123465/(content)/?$ /$1/pid/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Or if you already have `/example1/.htaccess` then use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example1/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/p123465/(content)/?$ $1/pid/$1 [L,NC,R]
```